# Upgrading from gwt2.4.0 to gwt2.5.0 giving exceptions

Tags: gwt-2.4, gwt-2.5

I have a application for that i have updated from gwt2.4.0 to gwt2.5.0. 
When i am running the application then seeing the following exception.

> ```
> 18:34:25.338 [ERROR] [OneViewUI] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/srapolu/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.java'
>  18:34:25.391 [ERROR] [OneViewUI] Line 276: The method setBridge(GWTBridge) in the type GWT is not applicable for the
> ```
>
> arguments (GWTBridge)

can you please help.

Comment: Can you share more stack trace...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. it turns out i had some references to the 2.4 version of gwt-dev.jar. make sure you don't have any and try again.