# Error: The method setBridge(GWTBridge) in the type GWT is not applicable for the arguments (GWTBridge)

Tags: java, maven, gwt

When I run my gwt app it throws this error:

```
00:01:09.317 [TRACE] Finding entry point classes
00:01:09.317 [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/xybrek/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.1/gwt-user-2.5.1.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.java'
00:01:09.317 [ERROR] Line 276: The method setBridge(GWTBridge) in the type GWT is not applicable for the arguments (GWTBridge)
00:01:09.320 [DEBUG] Checked 299 dependencies for errors.
00:01:09.320 [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.jboss.errai.enterprise.client.cdi.CDIClientBootstrap'
00:01:09.321 [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
00:01:09.321 [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
00:01:09.322 [ERROR] Failed to load module 'app' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36' at labs.localhost:35785
```

The version of GWT that my app uses is `2.5.1`

Comment: did you changed the GWT version. do you have multiple GWT version installed in Eclipse? When did you start getting this error?

Comment: Yes, I changed it from 2.4.0 to 2.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrading from gwt2.4.0 to gwt2.5.0 giving exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626729/upgrading-from-gwt2-4-0-to-gwt2-5-0-giving-exceptions).

Comment: Are you using `requestfactory-server` library If yes then it may still referring to 2.4.0 version. Changing the version to 2.5.0-rc1 may solve you problem.

Comment: Same discussion on [GWT web toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7527).